# How to replace the digits found in the string(using char variable) with the word corresponding to this digit?

Tags: c++, string, char

I need help on how to replace the digits found in the string(using the char variable) with the word corresponding to this digit.

For example ab56 to `abfivesix`

Here is the example

```
char a;
cout<<"a=";
cin >>a; //im going to enter 'abc345'
```

The output I want is like `abcthreefourfive`

I know how to replace it directly but the thing is I'm using `cin` command so the string is not yet declared

I have an idea to use the switch but have no idea how to start.

Comment: `char` can hold only 1 character. I think `a` should be a `std::string` instead of a `char`.

Comment: Regarding the assignment itself: one way would be to use a stringstream to build the output string. You can learn about it here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stringstream-c-applications/

Answer (score 1):

The motivation "im using cin command so the string is not yet declared" makes little sense - there is no difference between a string read from standard input and some other string.

I would do something like this, using a table instead of messing around with `switch`:

```
void with_words(std::ostream& os, const std::string& input)
{
    static const char* words[] = {"zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"};
    for (char c: input)
    {
        if (std::isdigit(c))
        {
            os << words[c - '0'];
        }
        else
        {
            os << c;
        }
    }
}
```

Test:

```
int main()
{
    // Output directly.
    with_words(std::cout, "abc123");
    std::cout << '\n';
    // Convert to a different string.
    std::stringstream s;
    with_words(s, "456def789");
    std::cout << s.str() << '\n';
    // User input.
    std::string in;
    std::cout << "? ";
    std::cin >> in;
    with_words(std::cout, in);
    std::cout << '\n';
}

...
$ ./test
abconetwothree
fourfivesixdefseveneightnine
? hell00O0!!1!
hellzerozeroOzero!!one!
```